# Database table editor for Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, mysql

I'm a software developer who will be building some relatively simple, but very custom components for a Wordpress website.  Each component will rely on data located in one or two database tables.

I'm looking for a plugin for Wordpress that gives a content editor the ability to maintain the data in those specific database tables.  Something like PHPMyAdmin, but just table data editing.  I'd like to avoid building an entire data management interface for these single table components.

Comment: Are you open to a solution that is not for Wordpress and then wrapping that into a WP plugin yourself?

Comment: @Mawg I guess I'm not opposed to a solution outside of Wordpress.  I just want to make things as easy and straightforward as possible for the content editors.

Comment: Then perhaps reword your question not to mention WP, find a good solution, then wrap a WP plugin around it